# Create and increment an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a problem with my array and I need your help.

I want to create an array with the result given by my `if`, for comparison with an another array.

```
if (grep {$community eq $_ } @communities) {
   my $community_matchs = "";
   print "$community;$login;$last_at;;$size;1\n";
   push (@matchs, $community_matchs); 
   #my array
}
else{
   print "$community;$login;$last_at;;$size;0\n";
}
```

Then, later on

```
if (grep {$c ne $_} @matchs) {
   print "$community;3\n";
```

I am a beginner and French, so be understanding with me.

Comment: You only ever push `""` to `@matchs`

Comment: You are setting ``$community_matchs =""`` and then pushing ``$community_matchs``.  This means your are pushing ``""``.  Maybe you need to do ``push (@matchs, $community)`` instead??

Comment: It's not clear what effect you want. Please would you explain what you want in `@matchs`, and the purpose of `$community_matchs`?

Comment: Show us the content of `@communities`, `$community` and `$c`.

Comment: Vorsprung - When I test `push (@matchs, $community)` I have the same result that `$community_matchs =""`

Comment: The array `@matchs` must contain variables `$community;$login;$last_at;;$size` in this pattern. `$community_matchs` must contain the result of `if`. `$c`is `@communities` but in variable and not in array.

Comment: The `grep {...} @communities` returns an array of matches, the `if(grep ...)` checks whether that array has any elements but it does not keep the matches found. The **then** part of the `if` appears to be trying to add the items found by the grep into `@matches`. Perhaps the code should have started with `@matches = grep ...; if ( @matches ) { ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Data::Dumper for debugging.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print 'matchs:'.Dumper(\@matchs);
```

You are not adding anything to `@matchs` so it is going to be empty.

Maybe this what are you looking for:

```
if (my @community_matchs = grep {$community eq $_ } @communities) {
   print "$community;$login;$last_at;;$size;1\n";
   push (@matchs, @community_matchs); 
   #my array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an illustration of what I think you're trying to do, but I would consider re-writing as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @communities = qw(community1 community2 community3 community4 community5 community6 community7 community8 community9);

my $community = 'community6';

my @matches;

foreach (@communities){
    if ($_ eq $community) {
        print "Match: $_\n";
        push (@matches, $_);
        # Do something else...
    }
    else {
        print "No match: $_\n";
        # Do something else...
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
No match: community1
No match: community2
No match: community3
No match: community4
No match: community5
Match: community6
No match: community7
No match: community8
No match: community9
```